# can we run our node.js project from a compressed “zip” file without extracting Zip file?

Tags: node.js

According to client requirement project should be less size. But generated source code size is much higher than the client demand. So this question raised how can we run node.js project from a zip file without extracting them. Is there any solution ? Please Help. Thanks You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Added after initial post*: It's not *yet* possible to run zipped code.

Have you looked into minifying the project's code?

There are packages that compress js and css files. They'll even concatenate them into a single js and a single css file for your deployment. This will decrease the file size and it will speed up page load because your application will be making fewer requests to the server.

If you want to do it with a minifier: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2
If you want to do it by hand: http://prettydiff.com/?m=minify

Also, have a look at webpack. I haven't used it personally, but it is described to do the same thing. It bundles your project for you.
https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: Thank You Mike Ferrari. I wil try this. But, is this possible to run project from a compressed file?

Comment: You can not run a code in a compressed format. Compression changes the content based on the algorithm used. As @mike correctly suggested you should minify your files it will reduce the size by a good amount.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, which will work if you're running on any Unix based system:

First, you need to combine your js source files into a single file. You could use a minifier to do this, or just cat them into one file.

Next, compress the file, e.g. `gzip <src.js>`. This will produce a compressed file like `scr.js.gz`.

You can now run this file using a command line like this: `gzip -cd src.js.gz | node`. What the command is doing is (1) unzipping the source file (-c) and writing the result to stdout (-d), and (2) piping the code to node, which will run it in interactive mode.

One caveat here is that, same as any other node app, any external dependencies in your code will need to be installed using npm before hand. If this is not possible in the target environment then you will need to remove those dependencies, perhaps by incorporating module code directly into your source.